# Skew-symmetric square root of diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Let $D=(d_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{n}$ be a diagonal matrix and $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{n}$ a skew-symmetric matrix, where $d_{ij},a_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $i,j$. Suppose the following equation holds:
$$
AA=D\,.
$$
In other words, $A$ is a square root of $D$.

**Question:** Does $d_{jj} \neq d_{kk}$ imply $a_{jk}=a_{kj}=0$?

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2119842/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and this has nothing to do with skew-symmetric matrices. Since $D=A^2$ is a polynomial in $A$, we have $DA=AD$ and hence $d_{jj}a_{jk}=a_{jk}d_{kk}$. It follows that $a_{jk}=0$ when $d_{jj}\ne d_{kk}$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! How does commutativity of $A$ and $D$ imply $d_{jj}a_{jk}=a_{jk}d_{kk}$?

Comment: @MK7 Compare the $(j,k)$-th entries of $DA$ and $AD$.

Comment: Of course, the $(j,k)$-th entry of $DA$ is precisely $d_{jj}a_{jk}$, while that of $AD$ equals $a_{jk}d_{kk}$. Thanks.